# How do I create a Microsoft Word half page template that mirrors my entry on the top into the bottom?

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I create a Microsoft Word half page template that mirrors my entry on the top into the bottom?

Yes, I could just only print to 1/2 the page and turn it around and print it again, but I'm trying to make sure how it will look with both printed on the page at the same time.

Alternately I am considering a table with the individual cells set to the size that I want the individual parts of the document to look and manual copy and paste.

Office 2010 in this case, I'm not sure what, if any, this would apply to previous versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may have just stumbled upon the answer I wanted:

Under Page Layout -> Margins -> Custom Margins -> Multiple Pages -> 2 Per Sheet and set all the margins to 0.75 (as that's what I wanted personally) and that seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one page of text in your document (that is, printing only fills half of one page), then you also need to enter "1,1" in the Pages field when you print.  This is the field where you would normally, enter the page numbers you want to print, IE: "2-10".  This tells Word to DUPLICATE the first page (which is really half a page) on the lower half of the printed page.

Comment: I don't have immediate access to Word to test this, but it seems like it would just print page 1 twice.  Are you saying that if the page has no explicit page break, this print option would start printing the second copy on the same page, immediately after the existing text?

Comment: Yes, it prints page one twice: once at the top of the page, and again at the bottom of the page. That is what I understood the OP wanted.

Comment: I just did a test- twice- with MS Word 2010. Filled one page with text up to half of the page, no page breaks etc. Gave the print command as suggested by Kirk. And...it did print two pages with text on top half. It did not what Kirk suggested.

Comment: Of course you have to set it to 2 pages per sheet as jcolebrand said. Perhaps you missed the word "also" in my reply.